# Help with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.uid, pf.title, pv.value FROM users AS u INNER JOIN 
profile_values AS pv ON pv.uid = u.uid 
INNER JOIN 
profile_fields AS pf ON pf.fid = pv.fid
ORDER BY u.uid
```

Which results in:

```
uid     title   value
1   First name  Jared
1   Last name   Boo
1   Organization    Acme
1   Website http://acme.com
1   Country Canada
6   First name  Nathan
6   Last name   Foo
```

I am attempting to use this result to create another result set which looks like this:

```
uid  First name  Last name  Organization  Website  Country
1    Jared       Boo        Acme          http...  Canada
6    Nathan      Foo
```

Am I going about this correctly?

Thanks in advance

*EDIT*

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `pass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `mail` varchar(64) default '',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `access` (`access`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `mail` (`mail`)
);

CREATE TABLE `profile_fields` (
  `fid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `explanation` text,
  `category` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`fid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `category` (`category`)
);

CREATE TABLE `profile_values` (
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`,`fid`),
  KEY `fid` (`fid`)
);
```

Comment: What happens when one user has more than one First name?

Comment: Also, are you planning to generate the column headers dynamically, or define in your query which fields it should extract?

Comment: A user won't have more than one of any of the fields.  It seemed logical to me to use the value of 'title' as the column headers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.uid, pf.title, pv.value
FROM users AS u, profile_values AS pv, profile_fields AS pf
WHERE pv.id = u.uid, pf.fid = pv.fid
ORDER BY u.uid
```

Is something like this what your looking for? What do the tables look like in terms of foreign keys? You may want to throw a `DISTINCT` in right after `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is all correct. It is not clear where organization, Website, Country fields should come from (as we don't know your database structure), but, for example, if `country` was a column of `profile_fields`, you would simply add `SELECT ..., pf.country ...`  to get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your schema is not accurately maintaining the required information. First off in the `User` table you have name as 1 attribute, thus splitting first and last name must be done by some other means. Secondly it is not clear where the company name or website information is stored. Please provide a logical mapping from the desired output to the attributes in the database tables.